# How can I search Gmail for emails where I was the first sender?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters

Email chains which are started by me are my responsibility to wrap up.

I'd like to see those emails.

How can I filter Gmail to show me only the email chains which I started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually quite simple, you just have to realize that Gmail automatically adds "Re:" and "Fwd:" to messages that are replied to or forwarded.  Just search for `is:sent subject:(-(Re OR Fwd))` for all threads that you initiated.

Answer (score 0):

The Gmail app doesn't have a simple way to identify conversations you initiated, however, you can leverage Gmail's **Signatures** to achieve your goal by including a unique string/code in all new conversations.

### Create a Gmail Signature

1. Navigate to [Gmail > See all settings > General](https://Settingshttps://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/#settings/general)
2. In the **Signature** section create a signature specifically for NEW conversations that includes a unique code, eg: `yyh7`
3. Select the signature under 'FOR NEW EMAILS USE' but not under 'ON REPLY/FORWARD USE'

[image]

### Searching Initiated Conversations

In your use case, you'd like to search for conversations that include `[yh7]` but are not yet wrapped up.  While there is no concept of 'wrapped up' in Gmail, you can apply a **User label** to conversations that you deem wrapped up (eg: `wrapped`) that would allow searching conversations you initiated for messages missing that label.

### Search String

Initiated by you and NOT wrapped up

`"yyh7" -label:wrapped`

### Searching in Conversation View is Weird

It should be noted that, in **Conversation View**, people often get search results they don't expect.

The crux of it is that Gmail's **Search in mail** conditions are applied to messages, however the results of these searches (in **Conversation View**) are conversations, NOT individual messages.  If a conversation includes ANY message that matches the search conditions, the conversation will be returned regardless if other messages in the same conversation are explicitly excluded by the same conditions.

In your case, **this is a benefit**, since you are looking for conversations you have NOT wrapped.  If you label a conversation `wrapped` because you think it is done, but new messages are later added to the conversation (whether sent or received), your search `"yyh7" -label:wrapped` will start returning that conversation again until you deem it wrapped once more and reapply the label `wrapped`.

This makes this approach **very reliable**.  You should however keep in mind that the opposite search would be unreliable.  `"yyh7" label:wrapped` would return all conversations with `wrapped` even if some the conversation had started up again and some of the messages were not marked `wrapped`.

The point is to keep to `"yyh7" -label:wrapped` for reliable results.